# Provisioning profile doesn't include the beta-reports-active entitlement

Tags: provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution, code-signing-certificate, xcode9.3, code-signing-entitlements

When I Archived the my build and then export form the Organizer for AdHoc Distribution.

It shows me for the selection of Profile. Now when I select my AdHoc provisioning profile. It will display error like this "Profile doesn't include the beta-reports-active entitlement."

I have regenerate the profile from developer.apple.com and archived once again but still the error is not remove.

I have also delete the old distribution and developer certificate from my keychain and create new certificate for both and then create new provisioning profile for my app. But still the error is coming when I export the build for AdHoc Distribution.

If I export the build for App Store Distribution then its work fine. but for AdHoc its showing me the error.

I have used XCode 9.3.

Suggest me How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Solution : It is the problem of Xcode version. I have upgrade the xcode form 9.3 to 9.4 and the error gone.